# Get rid of Actionbar bottom gradient

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to style the actionbar of my app (I use Actionbar Sherlock) by changing its background.

I set up a theme for my Application containing the following line to style the Actionbar:

```
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
```

I then created a style called `Actionbar`:

```
<style name="ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TitleText</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleText</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
</style>
```

Finally I have an image file named *actionbar_background.9.png* (3x5px) in my drawable folder, which looks like this:

[image: actionbar_background.9.png]

All of this style my actionbar just fine but there's a red to purple gradient at the bottom and I don't understand what creates that. Below are screenshots of the rendered ActionBar (the first one using the image above, the second one when I replaced the red pixels with green ones):

[image: screenshot of the rendered actionbar]
[image: screenshot of the rendered actionbar with green pixels instead of red one in the image]

I tried replacing the red with green in the image file and the gradient changes accordingly (from green to purple) but I still don't get why there is a gradient.

Anyone can point me into the right direction?

Comment: Make sure the 1px dark red is only one color and, I'm not sure, but it might be an optic illusion..

Comment: @Fllo I'm pretty sure it's not an illusion (see my edit ;-)). I double checked, the red pixels a the exact same. Anyway they're not supposed to be scaled if I understood correctly how 9-patch images work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following `layerlist` as the `drawable` for the actionbar `background`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/brand_orange" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/brand_purple" android:bottom="2dp" />
</layer-list>
```

All suggestions welcome for another approach using 9-patch.